# Twitter Search for all content instead of relevence

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on a web application that gets all tweets within a time period for a specific keyword. The Twitter4J API does not return all tweets but the most relevant. Is there a way to get all tweets for a specific keyword? I have tried setting the query result type to `RECENT`, but that is still unsuccessful at getting everything.

I know about Twitters streaming API but I am not able to collect data for a period of time. The search keyword can be for anything so collecting and storing so much data is not reasonable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {

    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("(amazon) AND (stock)");
    query.setCount(100);
    query.setLang("en");
    query.setResultType(Query.RECENT);
    query.setSince("2017-02-06");

    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    System.out.println("PRINTING:");

    int numberOfTweets = 0;
    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
        numberOfTweets++;
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + "-" + status.getCreatedAt() + ":");
        System.out.println(status.getText());
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfTweets);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on the Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. **Not all Tweets** will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

You cannot get *everything*.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to get a larger set of data? Any suggestions?

Comment: "Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead. "                  That means that you have to use the streaming api